# Multiple elements in sub-query

Tags: sql, mysqli

I am trying to write a query in the form of:

```
SELECT
   field_a.table AS x,
   field_b.table AS y,
   ( SELECT
       field_a.tableb AS a,
       field_b.tableb AS b,
    FROM tableb) FROM table
```

However, I get the following error message: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Is there any way this can be done or will I have to resort to multiple sub-queries? I just see it as quite inefficient.

Cheers

Comment: Please give more details: table and tableb definition, expected output, ideally some sample data...

Comment: What is the relationship between **tableb** and **table**

Comment: Each element of the select list corresponds to *one* result column.  In particular, a subquery appearing in the select list must yield a single result row having a single column.

Comment: Also, you seem to be writing qualified column names backward.  For example, column `field_a` of the table identified as `table` should be written `table.field_a`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

For your proposed query to make any sense at all, it must be the case that table `tableb` has only one row.  In that case, you can probably achieve your objective with a join instead of a subquery.  Maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT
  table.field_a AS x,
  table.field_b AS y,
  tableb.field_a AS a,
  tableb.field_b AS b
FROM
  table CROSS JOIN tableb
```

If in fact `tableb` has multiple rows, each correlated in some way with exactly one row of `table`, then you would instead perform an `[INNER] JOIN` using a join predicate corresponding to the appropriate relationship.  If you want anything more specific then you'll need to describe your data better.